# How do I filter down a subset of files based upon time?

Tags: bash, time, scripting, find, ls

Let's assume I have done lots of work whittling down a list of files in a directory down to the 10 files that I am interested in.  There were hundreds of files, and I have finally found the ones I need.

I can either pipe out the results of this (piping from `ls`), or I can say I have an array of those values (doing this inside a script).  Doesn't matter either way.

Now, of that list, I want to find only the files that were created yesterday.

We can use tools like `find -mtime 1` which are fine.  But how would we do that with a subset of files in a directory?  Can we pass a subset to `find` via `xargs`?

I can do this pretty easily with a `for` loop.  But I was curious if you smart people knew of a one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're in an array:

```
files=(...)
find "${files[@]}" -mtime 1
```

If they're being piped in:

```
... | xargs -d'\n' -I{} find {} -mtime 1
```

Note that the second one will run a separate `find` command for each file which is a bit inefficient.

If any of the items are directories and you don't want to search inside of them, add `-maxdepth 0` to disable `find`'s recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that won't recurse, though I'd just use John's `find` solution if I were you.

```
$: stat -c "%n %w" "${files[@]}" | sed -n "
     / $(date +'%Y-%m-%d' --date=yesterday) /{ s/ .*//; p; }"
```

The `stat` will print the name and creation date of files in the array.
The `sed` "greps" for the date you want and strips the date info before printing the filename.